# Display ISO-8859-1 characters in UTF-8 webPage

Tags: javascript, java, utf-8, iso-8859-1

How do I display iso-latin1 characters (for example : the symbol mu) in a web page that has encoding UTF-8 as in  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`
I change the encoding to `encoding="ISO-8859-1"` but I still get `?` instead of those Latin symbols.

Comment: Use this: `&#x03BC;`

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any "iso-latin1 characters". Some characters have an encoding in one or more of the iso-8859-x encodings.

If you like to see a character in a file with UTF-8 encoding which is capable of representing all characters for which a Unicode is defined (and which includes all characters for which an iso-8859-1 encoding - or any other iso-8859-x encoding - is defined) you can

- insert the byte sequence for the UTF-8 representation of that character
- use an entity, e.g `&#x03BC;`for μ (where the file type has such entities: XML, HTML)

Which you prefer mainly depends on the way the file is produced.